# MS-ACCESS: How to construct a practical timetable per date?

Tags: ms-access

Don't know how to merely google for an answer on this one: How does one go about constructing an ever-expanding per-date engagement timetable - that links an employee and work type to a specific date?

What I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

("RW" and "DO" is supposed to be user input stored in "tblEmployeeEngagement")

This is pretty easy to do with excel's tables, and index and match functions can do wonders, but I don't know how to get user-friendly results in access. Here's my table construction:

tblEmployees

- EmployeeID (autoincrement)
- First Name
- Last Name
- ...

tblWorkType

- WorkTypeID (autoincrement)
- ShortName (text, unique)
- Description
- ShiftStart
- ShiftEnd
- ...

tblDate

- DateID (autoincrement)
- Date (date, unique)
- CompanyOperational (bool)
- ...

tblEmployeeEngagement

- EngagementID
- EmployeeID (relationship with above)
- DateID (relationship with above)
- WorkTypeID (relationship with above)

Let's say these are the tables. Theoretically one can enter multiple Engagements for same person with same date, but this is not at all necessary and let's say this option is eliminated. How do I go about making editable query/table for easy input as the one in picture?

A crosstable constructs it exactly as I want it, but it is NOT editable (as in pic related), which is an issue.

I am open to completely removing "tblDate" and adding "Date" field in "tblEmployeeEngagement", but I still don't see how I would construct this sort of query/table without VBA. The desired result is for end-user to be able to populate "tblEmployeeEngagement" alone.
Help.

Comment: *"... I still don't see how I would construct this sort of query/table without VBA."*  Me neither.  You might be able to build a form based on your crosstab, with those user/date engagements presented as text boxes.  Clicking in one of the text boxes could open a popup to edit that engagement.  And I think you would need to revise the crosstab form's column headers to match the crosstab's current date range each time the form opens.  I don't know how that all could be done without VBA.

Comment: @HansUp I'm always trying to get the default pre-made solution if it's possible but in this case I guessed it won't be that easy. Thank you for confirming my thoughts! And the popup solution seems feasible. Time to get into the weeds I guess

Answer (score 1):

I would build a form that does not have a table behind it.

In the header I would have a typed header for Employee and then I would have 7 (or 10 or whatever) number of fields for the dates. Let's assume that you are putting in time in the past, VBA On Open could set the 1st label text to 7 days ago, 2nd to 6 days ago, 3rd to 5 days ago, etc. If you add a date that matches to your tbl and is non-working, simply lock and darken the fields underneath those dates.

Under employee label, I would have a drop-down to choose the employee. Next to that would be 7 fields which each have the choice of RW and DO.

The user would then select an employee from the drop-down and go across the days and set the dates to be RW or DO or blank depending on the status.

When the user clicks the Save (or Close or whatever ) button, the computer would then create records for each employee, each date, and each Engagement to the Engagement table.

If you want them able to edit these Engagements, you could bring in the data for each Employee during the date range given.

Hope this helps.